# spring batch job xml to flat file with composite tag

Tags: jaxb, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job to convert an xml file to flat file
the problem I'm facing at the composite xml tag . when tried without the composite id , the spring batch job works file .
So far I tried to create an XmlAdapter on the id (which is composed of num and alpha in xml file ) field , since I m new to this I couldn t make it working . any help is appreciated.

xml file:

```
<company>
    <record refId="1001">
        <name>ben</name>
        <age>31</age>
        <dob>31/8/1982</dob>
        <id>
            <num> 100 </num>
            <alpha>  aaaa   </alpha>
        </id>
    </record>
    <record refId="1002">
        <name>bou</name>
        <age>30</age>
        <dob>26/7/1983</dob>
        <id>
            <num> 200 </num>
            <alpha>  bbbb </alpha>
        </id>
    </record>
</company>
```

I want to get a flat file like this :

```
 ben,31,31/8/1982,100aaaa
 bou,30,26/7/1983,200bbbb
```

Report.java:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "record")
public class Report {

    private int refId;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Date dob;
    private Identifer id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "refId")
    public int getRefId() {
        return refId;
    }

    public void setRefId(int refId) {
        this.refId = refId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "age")
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JaxbDateAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JaxbDateAdapter.class)
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Identifer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Identifer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

}

jobDefinition.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <batch:job id="reportJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="xmlItemReader" writer="cvsFileItemWriter" 
                    commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="company" />
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:xml/Result.xml" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="reportUnmarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Read and map values to object, via jaxb2 -->
    <bean id="reportUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>model.ReportMapper</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cvsFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">

        <!-- write to this csv file -->
        <property name="resource" value="file:cvs/csvFile.csv" />
        <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />

             <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                <property name="delimiter" value="," />
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names" value="name,age,dob,id" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: What does your current job output?

Comment: ben,31,31/8/1982,  
 bou,30,26/7/1983,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by defining toString function in the JavaBean Id like this :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Id")
public class Id {
    int num;
    String alpha;
         @XmlElement(name="Num")
    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
         @XmlElement(name="Alpha")
    public String getAlpha() {
        return alpha;
    }
    public void setAlpha(String alpha) {
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  num + alpha ;
    }
```